# Use OAuth 2.0 Tokens to login to Salesforce.com

Tags: oauth, salesforce

Currently we are not using OAuth with our apps but we are working on making the shift, we have direct login and capture the user/pass that was entered and store those. We then turn around and use the stored credentials for a feature that allows the user to open a record within Salesforce.com, we pass the user/pass in to the login endpoint along with a starting URL to the specific record, this works great and is a well liked feature as it is a simple SSO from the App to Salesforce.com where the user can see all data that may not be visible within the app.

Moving to OAuth 2.0 and using the standard webflow, we no longer can capture the user/pass, which is actually a good thing as far as security is concerned. We would however like to keep this functionality, is there anyway of SSO'ing into Salesforce.com by passing along one of the OAuth tokens or some kind of sesson id?

After reading more and thinking about what OAuth accomplishes I feel like this probably isn't possible being that the tokens obtained are meant to be used only with the API and not with the front end system. I hope that I am wrong though and there is a way to login to the front end using these tokens.

**EDIT**

Ok I am editing to hopefully make this more clear. Currently user's authenticate using the login() API method with their user/pass, we store this user/pass locally (not ideal). We then sync a subset of data that the users can access anytime within the app, being that it is a subset, we have a feature to "SSO" to the Salesforce.com front-end. This simply opens Salesforce.com in a web-view (UIWebView) using the URL `https://ns8.salesforce.com/?pw=PASSWORD&un=username@example.com&startURL=/recordId`. This will log us in to Salesforce.com and open the specified record.

Moving forward we want to use OAuth 2.0 with the web flow so that we aren't handling the user/pass and so that we do not have to deal with Security Tokens or opening specific IP ranges to allow login without a Security Token.

With that said, is there anyway to use the tokens/credentials received from the OAuth authentication to open Salesforce.com, automatically log the user in, and goto a specific record?

I may have mis-used "single sign on" before, but in a sense, this simulates an SSO from our App to Salesforce.com, in that our users can touch a single button within the app and be logged in to the Salesforce.com web interface.

Comment: Token is kind of hand shaking mechanism to authenticate and introduce yourself.i suspect what you looking will not be possible to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you request an OAuth token, you can specify what scope it has, options include api only (the original type of tokens), or other options which include the ability to use the token with the UI pages. (see the scope parameter detail in the [help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&language=en)). One of the still missing peices is a way to bootstrap the UI with that token when all you can do is tell a browser/webview to goto a URL, but a widely used (but unsupported) way is via frontdoor.jsp, e.g. you'd open https://{instance}/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid={the_Access_token}&retURL={optional_relative_url_to_open} remember to URLEncode the 2 values.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I am going to test it out and accept the answer if it works out.

Comment: Thanks. This answer worked for us too. You mention that this is unsupported. Is there any other way that is officially supported by Salesforce?

Comment: No, there's no supported equivalent of frontdoor.jsp yet.

Comment: Winter 14 will offer supported frontdoor.jsp: https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf

Comment: frontdoor.jsp is supported as of Win 2014 for those who are reading this post now: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193348&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

So I think you are saying your application uses the SFDC username and password to just authenticate to retrieve a record from SFDC to display in your app?

IF this is correct - which I think it is - then you could just use the standard Salesforce Single Sign On system to authenticate. There is a guide [here](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_single_sign_on.pdf) which outlines the process of setting up a SAML SSO system with Pat Patterson writing an interesting feature on how the security system works [here](http://blog.superpat.com/2009/01/12/did-you-know-that-federated-identity-deployments-are-more-secure-than-you-think/). He has also written a great blog post on DeveloperForce [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_at_Salesforce.com) about the nitty details of OAuth in general for Force.com and not just the SAML setup. I have used the OAuth system in an iPad app against SFDC and it works quickly and easily. I can't see why your system should be unable to use the protocol as you desire.

Comment: Edited my answer to clear things up, I have not gone through all the SAML/SSO docs you posted yet. As you sound familiar with them, please let me know if one of those approaches will solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: superfell's answer is more specific with mine a general guide to the possible OAuth approaches on FDC. They will be useful to you as you go further down the path I imagine, but glad you got a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Direct access into Salesforce is a key benefit of SSO and definitely provided. I'm not sure where you read that SSO in Salesforce is API only. From the SSO PDF pbattisson linked for you:

> With single sign-on, users only need to memorize a single password to
>   access both network resources or external applications and Salesforce.
>   When accessing Salesforce from inside the corporate network, users are
>   **logged in seamlessly**, without being prompted to enter a username or
>   password. When accessing Salesforce from outside the corporate
>   network, users' corporate network login works to log them in. With
>   fewer passwords to manage, system administrators receive fewer
>   requests to reset forgotten passwords.

OAuth 1 & 2 are both supported, though I'm a fan of OAuth 2 since 1 has really finicky additional steps involving the order of parameters and their encoding sequences. I recently wrote an Apex-Twitter integration and quickly realized it [wasn't going to be as easy](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) as [Facebook, which uses OAuth 2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

But in your case it sounds like you just want to provide users with the ability to actually login to Salesforce and go to a specific landing page once authenticated. This is definitely doable.

Good luck!